# My GCE VM instance reset for an unclear reason?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a 48vCPU, 96GB RAM VM on Google Compute Engine. When I execute several docker containers, which perform some tasks, the VM instance seem to 'reset'.

The `gcloud compute operations list` is not suggesting anything, because it contains no entry at the timestamp, when reset happened.

Below is the monitoring information and syslog of the 'faulty' machine.
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3203.812836] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 46(veth5ec217a) entered disabled state
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3203.813443] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 47(veth2e644f5) entered disabled state
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3203.813824] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 48(veth83e9ba8) entered disabled state
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3204.008971] eth0: renamed from veth7e29e09
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3204.057313] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethd8ccbfc: link becomes ready
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3204.057405] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 45(vethd8ccbfc) entered blocking state
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3204.057408] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 45(vethd8ccbfc) entered forwarding state
Jan 14 17:18:08 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: vethd8ccbfc: Gained carrier
Jan 14 17:18:09 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3205.125463] eth0: renamed from vethb02bb32
Jan 14 17:18:09 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth5ec217a: Gained carrier
Jan 14 17:18:09 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3205.161119] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5ec217a: link becomes ready
Jan 14 17:18:09 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3205.161222] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 46(veth5ec217a) entered blocking state
Jan 14 17:18:09 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3205.161225] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 46(veth5ec217a) entered forwarding state
Jan 14 17:18:10 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: vethd8ccbfc: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3206.284834] eth0: renamed from veth2ab704d
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth83e9ba8: Gained carrier
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3206.336989] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth83e9ba8: link becomes ready
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3206.337073] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 48(veth83e9ba8) entered blocking state
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3206.337075] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 48(veth83e9ba8) entered forwarding state
Jan 14 17:18:11 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth5ec217a: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3207.220883] eth0: renamed from veth35b659d
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth2e644f5: Gained carrier
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3207.260969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth2e644f5: link becomes ready
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3207.261052] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 47(veth2e644f5) entered blocking state
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [ 3207.261056] br-0d70adaeac7e: port 47(veth2e644f5) entered forwarding state
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth83e9ba8: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1001...
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[17335]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 21047 (kill).
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1001.
Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of filip.
Jan 14 17:18:13 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-networkd[1204]: veth2e644f5: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of filip.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Started Session 360 of user filip.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Paths.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Timers.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Default.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Startup finished in 73ms.
Jan 14 17:18:21 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1001...
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[25738]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 27228 (kill).
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1001.
Jan 14 17:18:22 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of filip.

---- HERE IS WHERE THE RESET SEEM TO HAPPEN ---

Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-modules-load[808]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd-modules-load[808]: Inserted module 'ib_iser'
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-1026-gcp (buildd@lgw01-amd64-013) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 18:27:01 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-1026.27-gcp 4.15.18)
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-1026-gcp root=UUID=3d6dfdd5-865f-4188-80fb-f09f9f8b3269 ro scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=Y console=ttyS0
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bfffafff] usable
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfffb000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffbc000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000183fffffff] usable
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: Google Google Compute Engine/Google Compute Engine, BIOS Google 01/01/2011
Jan 14 17:18:54 vehicle-fleet-big-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: KVM
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd discard any live migration issue, according to Google Cloud Platform documentation about live migration:

> "Live migration does not change any attributes or properties of the VM
>   itself. The live migration process just transfers a running VM from
>   one host machine to another host machine within the same zone. All VM
>   properties and attributes remain unchanged, including internal and
>   external IP addresses, instance metadata, block storage data and
>   volumes, OS and application state, network settings, network
>   connections, and so on." https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration

So it's not possible that live migration could have changed anything inside your instance, also preemptibility option is off.

As you mentioned when running the gcloud compute operation lists, any operation that is displayed doesn't match with the timestamp this event happens, maybe try to look in the Activity dashboard and Stackdriver Logging.

Looking at your logs, it's interesting why the system does create a user slice, reach a shutdown target, and a few seconds later removes it, I'd suggest you to use the command **systemd-cgtop** to monitor the control groups of your instance and use the **last** command to see which users connected to your instance, timestamp and the source IP.

Finally, what kind of tasks are you performing with docker?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a regular reboot, initiated from inside of the VM - note all systemd's 'stopped' logs - they indicate systemd was doing things on purpose. There is a very low probability for GCE VMs to die (e.g. if there is sudden hardware failure) but it looks nothing like what you have here.

Also note `Jan 14 17:18:12 vehicle-fleet-big-2 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1001...` log line. I suggest you figure out what user has UID 1001 and check what were they doing around that time.